# How to read and load properatly JSON formated file

Tags: c#, json, treeview, command-line-arguments

I found hard times to understand what I am doing wrong. My goal is to read JSON formated text and load it to my winforms application window. Where I use check boxes in tree View. My Json file looks like:

```
          [
            {
            "ChildChecked": false,
            "ChildTitle": null,
            "NodeChecked": true,
            "NodeTitle": "Parent1"
        },
        {
            "ChildChecked": false,
            "ChildTitle": null,
            "NodeChecked": false,
            "NodeTitle": "Parent2"
        },
        {
            "ChildChecked": false,
            "ChildTitle": null,
            "NodeChecked": false,
            "NodeTitle": "Parent3"
        },
        {
            "ChildChecked": false,
            "ChildTitle": "Child31",
            "NodeChecked": false,
            "NodeTitle": null
        },
        {
            "ChildChecked": false,
            "ChildTitle": "Child32",
            "NodeChecked": false,
            "NodeTitle": null
        },
        {
            "ChildChecked": false,
            "ChildTitle": "Child33",
            "NodeChecked": false,
            "NodeTitle": null
        },
     ]
```

As you can see If NodeTitle is null, then this mean that this node is child and according that if nodetitle is null- this is parent node. My reading and loading looks like this:

```
private void LoadConfig(string path)
        {

            var cfgString = File.ReadAllText(path);
            var cfg = DocConfig.LoadFromString(cfgString);


            foreach (var part in cfg.Parts)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
                {
                    if (part.NodeTitle == "Parent1")
                    { 
                        node.Checked = part.NodeChecked;
                    }
                    if (part.NodeTitle == "Parent2")
                    {
                        node.Checked = part.NodeChecked;
                    }
                    if (part.NodeTitle == "Parent3")
                    {
                        node.Checked = part.NodeChecked;
                    }
                        foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
                    {
                        if (part.ChildTitle == "Child31")
                        {
                            child.Checked = part.ChildChecked;
                        }
                        if (part.ChildTitle == "Child32")
                        {
                            child.Checked = part.ChildChecked;
                        }
                        if (part.ChildTitle == "Child33")
                        {
                            child.Checked = part.ChildChecked;
                        }
```

My loading event holder is giving messages if my json file is loaded. It says that it is loaded, but he is not checking any check boxes which are written in JSon file. Maybe you could help me?

My saving method:

```
private void SaveConfig(string path)
        {
            var config = new DocConfig();
            config.Parts = new List<DocPart>();


            foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
            {
                { 
                    config.Parts.Add(new DocPart { NodeTitle = node.Text, NodeChecked = node.Checked });
                }

                        foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
                        {
                           config.Parts.Add(new DocPart { ChildTitle = child.Text, ChildChecked = child.Checked });
                       }



                var configString = config.SaveToString();
                File.WriteAllText(path, configString);

            }
```

And my DocConfig and DocParts classes:

Thanks.

```
public class DocPart
{
    public string NodeTitle { get; set; }
    public bool NodeChecked { get; set; }
    public string ChildTitle { get; set; }
    public bool ChildChecked { get; set; }
}

public class DocConfig
{
    public List<DocPart> Parts { get; set; }

    public static DocConfig LoadFromString(string jsonData)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DocConfig));

        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData));
        var config = (DocConfig)serializer.ReadObject(ms);


        return config;

    }
    public string SaveToString()
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DocConfig));
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, this);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()).PrettyPrintJson();
    }

}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a proper JSON file to me - I'd expect it to start with `[` and end with `]` to indicate that it's an *array* of items. It doesn't help that you haven't shown us `DocConfig.LoadFromString`, either...

Comment: DocConfig is just a class where I format a JSON file. If you want I can post it, but I think in this question it is not playing big part here.

Comment: @JonSkeet it starts with [ and ends with ]  . I will edit this :)

Comment: That JSON doens't describe a tree.  There is no way to tell which is the parent of a child node. Which are the parents of Child31, Child32 and Child33?

Comment: Yes, it does - it's what parses the data! How can that not be relevant? It's not at all clear why you've got nested loops though... shouldn't you only be checking or unchecking a particular node based on which part that node is meant to represent? All you're doing with `node` is checking or unchecking it (and getting its children) - you're not looking at its text or anything like that. We don't know how you *want* to identify which node maps to which JSON item, but it's not doing it now. (It would also really help if you'd put some effort into formatting your code in the question.)

Comment: Yes, guys I feel the same, that this is saving isn't in the right way. Maybe you could help me how to change this, I will add my saveconfig method and doconf class.

Comment: @JonSkeet I would put all my code, but its 500lines :/ and if question is with too much code no one would help me, so I am trying to put only what is mostly needed. I'm confused and don't know how to make it work. :/

Comment: What you should include is a *short* but *complete* example demonstrating the problem. First thing to do is validate whether the JSON is being parsed correctly. If it is, you don't need to include the JSON in your repro - just hard code the data. Next, you only need two or three nodes - not six. Next, we need to know how want to map a node in your tree to a `Part` object - we have no idea at all about that yet. (And why do you have the `command-line-arguments` tag? What does that have to do with anything?) Basically, you need to isolate the issue as far as possible before asking.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have about 20parent nodes and about 50child nodes in my project. command-line- arguments tag is because I want to use my json file as command line parameter. My json file exapmle gives you a look how my tree view mapped in Part object. I am trying to isolate issues with reading, but I don't know how :/

Comment: Well I've said already: check whether once you've parsed the JSON, your `DocConfig` object looks okay. If it does, then the JSON parsing is irrelevant to the question, as are the command-line arguments. (Just because you're *using* command-line arguments doesn't mean they're relevant to the question - you don't mention them anywhere in the question body.) If the JSON parsing *is* a problem, then you don't need any of the treeview parts. The question should be able *one* of those aspects - not both. You need to do some diagnostic work into working out which it is.

Comment: And the number of nodes in your real code is irrelevant - again, focus on creating a *minimal* example that still represents the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet I did a lot of diagnostic works. I were asking on this site how to read this treeview no one helped me for 4days :/ so I tried to build something my self and this what happened. I have written few more applications with JSON formatted document configurations and they were working in this principles like this DocConfig.

Comment: If you haven't done enough diagnostic work to figure out whether the problem is in reading the JSON or using the results, then you haven't done enough diagnostic work, I'm afraid. Again, this question should be about one aspect or the other - not both. This is my last comment on this question - I don't think it would be helpful to keep repeating the same thing. I strongly encourage you to read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints *thoroughly* though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data that describes a tree structure is a `List<DataNode`>. The `TreeRepository` class loads a json file into a `TreeView` and saves the `TreeView` data structucture into a json file:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace JsonTreeView
{
    public class DataNode
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        public List<DataNode> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public static class TreeRepository
    {

        public static List<DataNode> LoadDataNodes(string jsonFilePath)
        {
            var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);
            var dataNodes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataNode>>(json);
            return dataNodes;
        }

        public static void Load(this TreeView treeView, string jsonFilePath)
        {
            treeView.Nodes.Load(LoadDataNodes(jsonFilePath));
        }

        public static void Load(this TreeNodeCollection nodes, List<DataNode> dataNodes)
        {
            foreach(var dataNode in dataNodes)
            {
                var treeNode = nodes.Add(dataNode.Text);
                treeNode.Checked = dataNode.IsChecked;
                if (dataNode.Children != null && dataNode.Children.Count > 0)
                {
                    Load(treeNode.Nodes, dataNode.Children);
                }
            }
        }

        public static List<DataNode> GetDataNodes(this TreeView treeView)
        {
            var dataNodes = new List<DataNode>();
            AddNodesToList(treeView.Nodes, dataNodes);
            return dataNodes;
        }

        private static void AddNodesToList(TreeNodeCollection nodes, List<DataNode> dataNodes)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
            {
                var dataNode = new DataNode
                {
                    Children = new List<DataNode>(),
                    IsChecked = node.Checked,
                    Text = node.Text
                };
                dataNodes.Add(dataNode);
                if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    AddNodesToList(node.Nodes, dataNode.Children);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Save(this TreeView treeView, string jsonFilePath)
        {
            var dataNodes = treeView.GetDataNodes();
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataNodes, Formatting.Indented);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(jsonFilePath, json);
        }
    }
}
```

The form has a tree view a three buttons with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace JsonTreeView
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string jsonFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "TreeView.json");

        private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.treeView1.Save(jsonFilePath);
        }

        private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        }

        private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
            this.treeView1.Load(jsonFilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how `TreeView.json` file Looks like:

```
[
  {
    "Text": "Item 1",
    "IsChecked": false,
    "Children": [
      {
        "Text": "Item 1.1",
        "IsChecked": true,
        "Children": []
      },
      {
        "Text": "Item 1.2",
        "IsChecked": false,
        "Children": [
          {
            "Text": "Item 1.2.1",
            "IsChecked": true,
            "Children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Text": "Item 2",
    "IsChecked": true,
    "Children": [
      {
        "Text": "Item 2.1",
        "IsChecked": false,
        "Children": []
      },
      {
        "Text": "Item 2.2",
        "IsChecked": true,
        "Children": [
          {
            "Text": "Item 2.2.1",
            "IsChecked": false,
            "Children": []
          },
          {
            "Text": "Item 2.2.2",
            "IsChecked": false,
            "Children": []
          },
          {
            "Text": "Item 2.2.3",
            "IsChecked": true,
            "Children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Text": "Item 2.3",
        "IsChecked": false,
        "Children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For this tree view:

[image]

Comment: But if my tree view is dynamic, I can remove some of my parent or children node , will it still work? And if I want to load the json file as a command line parameter not like a button click event?

Comment: This code saves the TreeView into a json file, no matter what nodes it has. It's totally dynamic. And the code loads a TreeView from a json file, no matter how many DataNodes has, as long as the structure of the json file is the expected structure. You can add or remove nodes as you want, it will work.

Comment: I should initialize my treeview elements in load event handler or no?

Comment: maybe you could show me how you add elements to this program? because I am getting tons of compiling errors.

Comment: What errors? It compiles and runs fine on my machine

Comment: It is not getting values of some elements. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: here you have the project: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4DF37CD14885C0E2!969&authkey=!AAkBHWd124zziUA&ithint=folder%2cjson